# Transposition Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

This question is somewhat simple:

If we write the transposition of a matrix like this:

```
A_transposed = T.A
```

where T is the operator performing the transposition, can I find a matrix form for this operator, that is independent of the matrix A ? (In other words that would transpose any matrix the size of A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

Take $A = I_n$, this would imply that $T = I_n$, but clearly, $A^T \neq I_n A$ if $A$ is not symetric

Comment: oh....silly me. Thanks :)

Comment: does this imply any deeper truths about the „transposition operator“? for example that it's not linear?